# Is there a way to determine the frequency of words in a column separated by comma in excel?

Tags: excel

I can count the number of times a specific word appears in an excel sheet column using "countifs"

However, is there a way to automatically show the most common words and the frequency of appearance in a column of data? For eg. in the sample image, column A has rows with different words aa, am, aq...separated by a comma. I would like to calculate the most common words and the frequency of appearance as shown by column C.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HCdZ.png)

Is there a way to achieve this in Excel?

Comment: Are the values always the same length (none of the values are substrings of any of the others) ?   If so, something like this would work: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/frequency-table-for-comma-separated-list-in-cells.589640/  I can make an example if that's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For O365:

`=LET(α,A1:A10,β,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,α),", ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),γ,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(β)),δ,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(β))^0,N(β=γ)),TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(2),γ,δ),δ,-1)))`

Comment: Thanks!! How to modify it for random words (case, meta, cycle), etc. in column A. Also, how do I import the data from another sheet into this formula? What does α, β represent? Can I do this? =LET(α,Data!E2:Data!E4000,β,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,α),", ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),γ,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(β)),δ,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(β))^0,N(β=γ)),TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(2),γ,δ),δ,-1)))

Comment: Re "*How to modify it for random words (case, meta, cycle), etc.*", not sure what you mean. That's precisely what you have in the image you posted. The length of the strings is not important: what is important is that they are consistently separated by the same delimiter, i.e. ", ".

Comment: Yes, you can set α to be a range from another sheet.

Comment: α, β. etc. are simply names assigned to parts of the calculation. Amend their names if you want.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I understand that the strings length doesn't matter. However, can this be made to work if there's no space between two strings i.e. ab,ac,ad,aa  ?

Comment: Sure. Just change the two instances of `", "` in the formula I posted to `","`.

Comment: Just one final question.  Suppose I want to first select only those rows containing the string "forward" in column F. (F2:F10,"forward") and then carry out the above operation for those rows only. Any advise for that?

Comment: `=LET(α,A1:A10,β,F1:F10,γ,FILTER(α,β="forward"),δ,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,γ),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),ε,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(δ)),ζ,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(δ))^0,N(δ=ε)),TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(2),ε,ζ),ζ,-1)))`

Comment: @Jos Woolley How about this beautiful function for Excel-2019 users?

Comment: @Losai So that would mean no `SEQUENCE`, `UNIQUE` or `SORTBY`, correct?

Comment: @ Jos Woolley Yes. No 365 functions